# Is there anyway I can add a text field in iOS swift which takes multiple values?

Tags: ios, swift

Like it has to take 5 names one after the other when the enter is pressed.

I know doing it by using the add button but do not know how to read with the go button on key pad.

Comment: Why not use 5 text fields?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you're asking.

If you want a single `UITextField` that takes an input, responds to tapping the return/go button by accepting that text and then clearing the field for the next entry, you can make you view controller the delegate of the text field and implement the `textFieldShouldReturn` method.

That method gets called when the user presses return. You could use it to fetch the contents of the field, validate them, and if they are ok, clear out the field for the next entry.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to set a text field to allow you to enter 5 values without hitting enter, the only way to do it would be to override the UITextField delegate to check for another value, like space or "," and execute the textFieldShouldReturn method.

This isn't really advisable though...

I agree with Duncan, the correct way to do it is to require the user to hit Enter/Return/Go, and use the delegate methods to not leave the control, but clear it out and get ready for a new entry.